# How to make Html.ValidationMessage if I use ViewModel ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble using Html.ValidationMessage because I use ViewModel,

this is my Controller

```
    public ActionResult SetDataInDataBase()
    {
        ViewData["jenisList"] = new SelectList(db.isengs, "jenis", "jenis");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetDataInDataBase(CostVM model)
    {

        informasi item = new informasi();

        if (model.nama == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "This Field Cant Empty");
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            item.nama = model.nama;
            item.alamat = model.alamat;
            item.jk = model.jk;
            item.kelas = model.kelas;
            item.jenis = model.jenis;
        }

        db.informasis.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Register", new { id = item.id, id2 = item2.Id });

    }
```

this is my RazorView

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nama:</label>
        @Html.TextArea("nama")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Alamat:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="alamat" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>JK:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="jk" value="L" required/>L<br />
        <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="jk" value="P" />P<br />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Kelas:</label>
        <select name="kelas" required>
            <option value="">--Pilih Kelas--</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Jenis:</label>
        <div >
            @Html.DropDownList("jenis1", ViewBag.jenisList as SelectList, "--Jenis--", new { required = "required" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make if `model.name` is empty, show a notice or Message error "This Field Can't Empty", but I dont understand because I use ViewModel

Can someone help me show Validation Message if `model.name` empty?

Comment: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` with `@Html.TextAreaFor`, `@Html.TextBoxFor` and `@Html.DropDownListFor` should be used if you're using a viewmodel class, and mark corresponding properties as `[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field can't be empty")]`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I already sue your code, but  I got error in this line `@Html.DropDownList("jenis1", ViewBag.jenisList as SelectList, "--Jenis--", new { required = "required" })` if  a column name is empty, maybe my `return` is wrong but I dont know how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below to validate error thorugh model

```
[Required (ErrorMessage= "jenis selection is Required")]  
public string jenisList { get; set; }
```

and if you want to bind drop down list using viewbag, just use Viewbag in your related action method in controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SetDataInDataBase()
{
    ViewBag.jenisList  = new SelectList(db.isengs, "jenis", "jenis");
    return View();
}
```

Write below code in view

```
@Html.DropDownList("jenis", (SelectList)ViewBag.jenisList  , "-- Choose --")
@Html.ValidationSummaryFor(model => model.jenisList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: I already sue your code, but I got error in this line @Html.DropDownList("jenis1", ViewBag.jenisList as SelectList, "--Jenis--", new { required = "required" }) if a column name is empty, maybe my return is wrong but I dont know how to fix this

Comment: try now hope its help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is example how you can use validation with a strongly-typed viewmodel bound to view:

**Model**

```
public class CostVM
{
   // required property attribute
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field can't be empty")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // other properties
}
```

**View**

```
@model CostVM

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

If you want to show all validation errors, use validation summary feature:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Reference: [Performing Simple Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/performing-simple-validation-cs)

Comment: I used your code, but I got error in this line `@Html.DropDownList("jenis1", ViewBag.jenisList as SelectList, "--Jenis--", new { required = "required" })`

Comment: @Ihsan if you want to bind to model best way to do that is to use DropDownListFor(m => m.JenisList.....) But if you still want to use DropDownList("name") the 'name' should be exactly the same as property in your model.

Comment: wouldnt it show error when user first loads the view as `model.Name` will be blank the first time (get request)